# Get property with matching other properties

Tags: javascript

I have a fairly simple JavaScript object and I need to reference one of the properties by using other known properties.

```
{
"PM":"Joe Smith",
"Consultant":"joesmith@joesmith.com",
"Project":"ContainerStore",
"Notes":"This is my awesome note"
}
```

So using the above as an example, I will have the Project, Consultant & PM and I need to return the notes for that given combination.

Comment: Are you wanting to find the json object that matches PM and then get the Notes portion of that object?

Comment: So I have an array of JSON objects in like the example above. I am looping through the array and for each index I have the PM, Consultant & Project, I need to get the notes for that combination.

Comment: Are you talking about JSON (text) or about JavaScript objects? Please read the usage description of the `json` tag.

Answer (score 3):

**THIS ASSUMES THAT YOU CAN USE ES6 ARRAY.FIND**
This is the browser support for it:

Chrome: 45.0
Firefox (Gecko): 25.0 (25.0)
Internet Explorer: No support
Edge: 12
Opera: 32.0
Safari: 7.1

So let's say that we know the PM, Consultant, and Project, maybe held in an object like so:

```
var known = {
  "PM": "John Smith",
  "Consultant": "Jim Bob",
  "Project": "Awesome Project"
}
```

and then we have a list of objects inside of an array like so:

```
var listOfProjects = [ {....}...]
```

What we are wanting to tell our working is `Find the object that matches my known object`. And luckily for us, JavaScript array's have a `find` method, which we can pass in a function, like so:

```
var foundProject = listOfProjects.find(function(project){
 return project["PM"] === known["PM"] && 
        project["Consultant"] === known["Consultant"] && 
        project["Project"] === known["Project"]
})
```

Or we can make it a little bit cleaner with another higher-order function called `every` like so:

```
// Loop through the listOfProjects and return the first one that
// returns true 
var foundProject = listOfProjects.find(function(project){
         // Loop through all of the keys inside of our known object
         // and return true or false if every single one matches
         // the given condidtion
  return Object.keys(known).every(function(knownKey){
            // use the key to see if known at knownKey is equal to
            // what you find inside of project at the same key
           return known[knownKey] === project[knownKey]
         })
    })
```

Either way, foundProject will be the actual project object, so if we just wanted the "Notes" key, we can then do:

```
var notesForFoundProject = foundProject["Notes"]
```

If you cannot use Array.find, the below will work the same:

```
var known = {...}
var listOfProjects = [...]
var found;
for(var i = 0; i < listOfProjects.length; i++){
  var current = listOfProjects[i]
  if(current["PM"] === known["PM"] && 
            current["Consultant"] === known["Consultant"] && 
            current["Project"] === known["Project"]){
     found = current;
     break;
  }
}

var notes = found["Notes"] || false
```

Comment: please mention es6.

Comment: @NinaScholz I did not know that I used ES6. I thought that Array#extras were a part of ES5. According to [this](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/what-they-didnt-tell-you-about-es5s-array-extras--net-28263) article they are ES5 spec.

Comment: not all is part of ES5. [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) is part of ES6.

Comment: Huh! Ya learn something new every day! I will edit my comment to clarify, along with browser support for Array.find. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: you could add the source as well.